Make list of variables persistent flutter
I have a situation where I need to persistent some List of boolean variables that I am using to track three cards in normal and expanded state. So what i wanted is that if all the cards are closed or all are expanded it should notify the parent widget. The problem now is that once i reverse the state of the current card clicked via index, the other cards state automatically revert back to false, instead of retaining the value of the other items. This makes the boolean in my callback to send a wrong value to the parent.
class SummaryTrackerCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final TrackableType cardCategory;
  final List<TrackerEvent> events;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onExpandedChanged;

  const SummaryTrackerCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.cardCategory,
    required this.events,
    required this.onExpandedChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SummaryTrackerCardState createState() => _SummaryTrackerCardState();
}

class _SummaryTrackerCardState extends State<SummaryTrackerCard> {
  late List<bool> cardExpandedStates;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Initialize with 3 items, all set to false
    cardExpandedStates = List.filled(3, false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Filter events based on cardCategory
    List<TrackerEvent> filteredEvents = widget.events
        .where((event) => event.trackableType == widget.cardCategory)
        .toList();

    // Calculate total and average duration
    int totalDuration = filteredEvents.fold(0, (sum, event) {
      if (event.trackable?.startTime != null &&
          event.trackable?.endTime != null) {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.parse(event.trackable!.startTime!);
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.parse(event.trackable!.endTime!);
        int durationInMinutes = endTime.difference(startTime).inMinutes;
        return sum +
            (durationInMinutes / 60).ceil(); // Convert minutes to hours
      } else {
        return sum;
      }
    });
    int averageDuration = filteredEvents.isNotEmpty
        ? (totalDuration ~/ filteredEvents.length).round()
        : 0;

    // Check if this card is expanded
    bool isExpanded = cardExpandedStates[widget.cardCategory.index];

    return Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            // Toggle the expansion state of the current card
            cardExpandedStates[widget.cardCategory.index] =
                !cardExpandedStates[widget.cardCategory.index];
          });
          // Check if all cards are closed
          bool isAllCardsClosed =
              cardExpandedStates.every((state) => state == false);

          // Notify the parent widget about the expansion state
          widget.onExpandedChanged(!isAllCardsClosed);
        },
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          height: isExpanded ? 150.h : 77.h,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              // Display icon based on cardCategory
              SvgPicture.asset(
                HelperMethods()
                    .getSummaryTrackerCardIconPath(widget.cardCategory),
                width: 18,
                height: 18,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.h),
              // Display average duration or count based on cardCategory
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 4),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: HelperMethods()
                      .getSummaryTrackerCardColor(widget.cardCategory),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(99),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  widget.cardCategory == TrackableType.Sleep
                      ? "${averageDuration}h/d" // Display average duration for Sleep
                      : "${filteredEvents.length}x/d", // Display count for Diaper or Feeding
                  style: bodyBold.copyWith(
                    color: HelperMethods()
                        .getSummaryTrackerTextColor(widget.cardCategory),
                    fontSize: 13.sp,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Display additional information if the card is expanded
              if (widget.cardCategory == TrackableType.Diaper &&
                  isExpanded) ...[
                SizedBox(height: 6.h),
                DropdownRoutineIcon(
                  imgPath: Assets.images.svg.diaperRoutineIcon.path,
                  itemCount:
                      "${filteredEvents.where((event) => event.trackable?.category == TrackableCategory.Poop.name).length}x",
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 6.h),
                DropdownRoutineIcon(
                  imgPath: Assets.images.svg.diaperPeeRoutineIcon.path,
                  itemCount:
                      "${filteredEvents.where((event) => event.trackable?.category == TrackableCategory.Pee.name).length}x",
                ),
       
             
              ],
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            // Toggle the expansion state of the current card
            cardExpandedStates[widget.cardCategory.index] =
                !cardExpandedStates[widget.cardCategory.index];
          });
          // Check if all cards are closed
          bool isAllCardsClosed =
              cardExpandedStates.every((state) => state == false);

          // Notify the parent widget about the expansion state
          widget.onExpandedChanged(!isAllCardsClosed);
        },
   

I tried handling it here by only reversing the index of the currently selected card but I notice that the others automatically reverse to false by default which is not what I want. I want the states persistent and only the currently tapped one reversed.
